# Symfony4: Connect to database dynamically using URL

Tags: symfony4

I want to connect to a database using a parameter provided by the URL like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/DATABASE_1/
```

This will redirect to the login page using that "DATABASE_1" as the database to connect to.

I am new to Symfony and working with controllers, I've been a SQL developer all my life and I'm trying my hand at some new stuff. I already have a login form with authentication working perfectly using the Symfony docs with the database configured at .env file (https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/security.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should not to connect to database from your controller and handle database connection directly. The way it works is declaring configuration for Doctrine in config/packages/doctrine.yaml. Doctrine connects to database by itself. To work with database in controllers, for example, you need to get Doctrine instance firstable. Like this:

`$post = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Post::class)
        ->findOneBy(['slug' => $postSlug]);`

And then you can easily fetch something from database via your `Repository`.

Check this link:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I guess you could make different `VirtualHost` tha point to your URLS and add different `ENV` parameters thats contains your doctrine connection string.

[On this link](https://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html), there are example to set Env param in VirtualHost